# disable y-axis max and min values on nvd3 boxplot

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, boxplot, axis-labels

I am using nvd3 boxplot and would like to remove the max and min values being shown in the plot. For example, I ***do not*** want the values **7** and **68** to be displayed on the y-axis for the chart below.

[image]

Any suggestions as to how I can do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rendering the chart do:

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-axisMaxMin-y").remove(); //it will remove the max min
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yyOfaw7oW3eCCJQtyLBN?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to remove only the max value on Y and still display 0 (the min value?)

Comment: may be something like this `d3.selectAll(".nv-axisMaxMin-y")[0][1].remove();` code like this http://plnkr.co/edit/KlGywHlxOyPo3naTYcRp?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the object property and deletion methods is calling the `showMaxMin` method on the chart object itself:

```
chart.yAxis.showMaxMin(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

set     chart : {
          yAxis: {
                   showMaxMin : false
                  }
         }